# How to add a video for both platforms in splash screen in react native expo

Tags: expo, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-ios

I'm developing a react native app using expo and I'm trying to add a 2-seconds video in the splash screen, I googled everywhere and couldn't find anything that works on Expo.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tahir Ali I figured it out by adding a setTimeout(boolean, video duration) when the app loads in **App.js** as follows:

```
export default function App{

const[loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {setTimeout(()=>setLoading(false),5000)}, []);


return( loading ? <LoadingScreen/> : <HomeScreen/> )}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add videos to the the splash screen in expo. Expo does not allow developers to fully custamize the splash screen, the only custamisation you can do in the default expo splash screen is that you can change the backgroundColor and the image.

If you want to add your own splash screen with a video. I recommend that you create a new splash screen component.

Comment: Thank you, but my question was how to add this to the splash screen, all I know that is only accessible by app.json

Comment: And how load that screen instead of the splash one? is that possible to load another screen?